# Set custom bibtex call in Vim latex suite on windows (to add --include-directory)

Tags: bibtex, vim

I would like to use one .bib file for everything and not have to keep a copy in each project's folder. By reading around I see that if I were calling bibtex manually, then I could add the string `--include-directory` with the path to the .bib file (I plan on keeping the .bib file with my other latex style files).

In my _vimrc file I do set some g: variables for latex (like to set latex, pdf viewer, etc), but I can't find anything in the [documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html) about a g: variable for the bibtex call. Is this possible? Or do I have to specify the full path in my `\bibliography{}` call?

Thanks!

Comment: On Linux and TeXLive, I know for a fact that specifying the relative path in `\bibliography{}` works for keeping a bib file in a different directory. You may also want to look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/bib-library-file-in-a-different-directory-how-to-use-mendeley-centralised-bi).

Comment: Thanks, Willie! How did I miss that one? I guess I was too focused on the `--include-directory` string. I switched to windows and it's a pain to fool around with the read only folders, so I have a user folder for my .sty files. Setting the path in `\bibliogrpahy{}` does work, but I like to work lazier (although I spend more time looking for the answer than I save). I'll vote to close if no one offers an `--include-directory` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the file `$VIM/vimfiles/ftplugin/tex.vim` if you don't have it yet, and in it add the line

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_bib = g:Tex_BibtexFlavor . ' --include-directory /your/dir/here $*'
```

Comment: I also recently found that I can add to a directory to path for MikTex (I should have know there was a different angle than the vimrc file). http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html