# Setting environment variables for latex and bibtex in .bashrc

Tags: paths, bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.bib library file in a different directory, how to use? (Mendeley centralised .bib file)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/bib-library-file-in-a-different-directory-how-to-use-mendeley-centralised-b)

I recently started using TeX to write journal articles. I use TeX Live version 2009-10 on a laptop running Ubuntu 10.10 (64-bit). I edit and compile the tex files using vim and vim-latexsuite.

Currently for each journal article I have all associated tex, bib, eps, etc. files in individual folders. I would like to simplify my life a bit and have a dedicated folder containing a "master" bib file - And maybe another folder for my custom style files.

My problem is that can't figure out how I should define the PATH, and other environment variables in my .bashrc file to find the necessary support files (e.g., the .bib file). Which variables do I need to set? PATH? MANPATH? TEXINPUTS? BIBINPUTS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short version: I would put the BIB files to `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/myfiles/myfile.bib` and style files to `~/texmf/tex/latex/myfiles/myfile.sty` for example.

Long version: try

```
kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'
kpsexpand '$TEXMFLOCAL'
```

which will show you where you can put your local files, so that TeX will find them out-of-the-box. By default this is `~/texmf` (for your personal files) and `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` (for system-wide additions). Inside that tree you need to follow [TDS standard](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tds). For BIB files that would be:

```
BIBINPUTS = .;$TEXMF/bibtex/bib//
```

That is default value in TeX Live 2011 at least. You may check `texmf.cnf` on your system if the value is any different, or try to run one of the following commands:

```
kpsexpand '$BIBINPUTS'
kpsewhich --expand-path '$BIBINPUTS'
```

This will tell you where BibTeX searches for BIB files.

If you need those files only for a couple of projects and/or don't want to pollute your home folder, the cheapest trick is to create a TDS structure anywhere on the disk and only set `TEXMFHOME` to point to that location.

Setting `TEXINPUTS` and `BIBINPUTS` is not recommended. Setting `PATH` only helps you to find binaries like `pdftex`, but then `pdftex` should be able to find `texmf.cnf` and that file contains enough information to find everything else. You can override any setting from `texmf.cnf` with environmental variables, but I would suggest you to place the files to locations where TeX expects them as opposed to setting variables.