# Paths in TeXStudio

Tags: bibtex, paths, texstudio

At least, in teTeX/Linux, one can use environment variables like `TEXINPUTS`, `BIBINPUTS`, `BSTINPUTS` to change default directories.  In TeXStudio/Mac, how to access these like variables to specify others directories than the defaults? Specifically, I have my own `bibstyle.bst` file with the other tex files in just one working directory but `bibtex` can't see it.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but `bibtex` should find your `.bst` file if it is in the same directory as your source file, or in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more or less direct answer. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and TexStudio 2.4. I have given up on the environment variables and other `bibtex` [command line solutions](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/bibtex.html). An elegant workaround consists of following [Mojca Miklavec's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31339/setting-environment-variables-for-latex-and-bibtex-in-bashrc). Here is a summary:

1. Run `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` in your console/terminal.
2. The path generally corresponds to `~/texmf` on a standard TeXLive distribution. If the displayed path doesn't exist (like in my case) then put your `.bst` files under `~/texmf/bibtex/bst` and your `.bib` files under `~/texmf/bibtex/bib`.

The `bibtex` calls from TexStudio should be able to run smoothly now.

Comment: The default behavior of TeX Live is that `$TEXMFHOME` resolves to `~/texmf` on Unix systems, but to `~/Library/texmf` if installed via MacTeX on Mac OS X.

Comment: ... and your custom style files can be put e.g. in `$(kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME')/tex/style/`. In my case (style and bib files in a specific directory that's under version control), I could use symlinks, e.g. `ln -s $proj/doc/tex/style .` in `.../tex/`. Now it all works well!

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment above into an answer, just because I had to Google it all over again after getting a new Mac, and rediscovering this Q&A (and my comment).

For people with Mac OS X and who want to add a folder of styles from, say, a project you have under source control, do this (in a shell):

```
tmp=$(kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME')/tex
mkdir -p $tmp
cd $tmp
ln -s your_project_path/docs/tex/style .
```

(Amend the path to the folder you want to add, of course).

No need to restart texstudio. Just hit F5 (build and view) and now everything should work fine.