# Centralised .bib file on Mac

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, mactex

I'm wanting to place my `.bib` file where `LaTex` can easily find it, within my local Tex tree, under `texmf`.

I've already tried looking at the other centralised `.bib` posts here but they do not appear to be working for me. ([.bib library file in a different directory, how to use? (Mendeley centralised .bib file)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/bib-library-file-in-a-different-directory-how-to-use-mendeley-centralised-b))

Setup:
Mac OSX El Capitan.

MacTex 2016, 
LaTexiT.

Using TexMaker for the editor.

I've so far tried placing the bib file in several locations to see if it will compile and find it however it fails to find it.

These locations are as follows:

1. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bib/local`
2. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bib/`
3. `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib`

In my `.tex` file I have is `\bibliography{library}` where the `.bib` file is named `library.bib`

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as *samcarter* did in my edit. (too fast for me!)

Comment: What if you use `\bibliography{<absolute-path>/library.bib}`? It will be the same for each of you documents, and obvious. I know it's not what you're asking for, but seems a legit workaround for me.

Comment: 1+2 looks okay to me. Did you run `mktexlsr`? What do you get if you call `kpsewhich -show-path=bib` on a terminal? Are the pathes you are trying to use in the output?

Comment: @ebo, thanks. I'll just go for the absolute path, easier i guess.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest place to put local files with MacTeX is your local `texmf` folder which is located in:

```
~/Library/texmf
```

Files you put in this `texmf` folder will be found automatically without the need to use `mktexlsr`.

See the following question for how to set one up:

- [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2693)

Bibliography files go in:

```
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib
```

If you use multiple machines as I do, my actual `texmf` folder is kept in Dropbox and I have a symbolic link in the `~/Library` folder of each machine. To do this, make the folder in Dropbox and then from the Terminal do:

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/texmf ~/Library/texmf
```

#### Update for MacOS 12.x

Changes to how Files on Demand are treated by the MacOS can lead to files in a Dropbox linked `texmf`  not loading, since although the files exist, their content doesn't. Because of this, it's best to set the `~/Dropbox/texmf` folder to have a "Make available offline" status. This can be done using the Finder: right-click (or control click) on the folder icon and choose the "Make available offline" Dropbox item. See [MacTex 2022 issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642493/2693) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution (or workaround) is to give the absolute path to your file as the argument of the `\bibliography{}` macro, e.g. `\bibliography{/home/user-name/papers_and_stuff/library.bib}`.
 The call for the `.bib` file will thus be identical in all your documents.