# Using one .bib file for all .tex files

Tags: bibtex

I would like to maintain single .bib file for all my papers/lecture notes etc.

It looks like I have to save .bib file in the same folder where I have the .tex file.

This force me to copy paste the .bib file in multiple folders.

Suppose I add a reference in one of the .bib files, It will not show the change in other .bib file. It might be difficult to remember where I have added.

So, Is there any solution for such problem?

Comment: Please consider not to suggest JabRef/mendeley or any such. I am simply not capable of doing that magic. . :)

Comment: Please read my last comment. These directories are all part of your TeX distribution. LEAVE THEM ALONE! :) There is no problem. And adding this image just makes your question more confusing. You need to make a `texmf` directory in your *own* home folder. Not inside `/usr/local` or `/etc/` etc.

Comment: If your home folder doesn't contain a `texmf` directory, then you need to create one yourself. I posted a link that explains how this works. There's also a link there to a shell script on my github that will create it for you if you prefer.

Comment: I believe there home folder does not contain texmf directory.. When I opened the terminal and run "~/texmf'' it said "bash: /home/name/texmf: No such file or directory" It means there is no texmf directory in home folder. Right? I will create one..

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you... Please guide my through your shell script to create a texmf directory...

Comment: You don't really need the script. Just do `cd ~;mkdir -p texmf/bibtex/bib` and you should have what you need. You can add other directories later.

Comment: @AlanMunn :) I did it... When I run "~/texmf" it says "bash: /home/name/texmf: Is a directory"

Comment: Well of course. It makes no sense to "run" it. It's not a program, it's just a folder. Now put your `.bib` file inside `~/texmf/bibtex/bib` and you will be good to go.  It seems that you need to learn a little basic Linux skills. This is not the place for that.

Comment: Yes. I donot have any idea about linux.. I understand that it is not a place to learn about linux.. Sorry for that... Thanks for helping me out :) I did not think it is this easy...

Comment: @AlanMunn It is working..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a master `.bib` file stored in your local `texmf` directory.  It needs to be placed in the `bibtex/bib` directory within that.

So if your `.bib` file is called `MyBigBibFile.bib` then on a Linux system it would typically go here:

```
~/texmf/bibtex/bib/MyBigBibFile.bib
```

On a Mac it would go here:

```
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/MyBigBibFile.bib
```

If your local `texmf` folder doesn't exist, just create it yourself and make sure you also make the `bibtex/bib` directories.  See [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693) for more details on this.

If you're using MikTeX, it depends on how you created your local directory. See [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/2693) for details on how to do that.

Comment: I am using TexStudio.. Is the procedure same?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik TeXStudio is simply your editor and plays no role in this. What OS are you using?  Do you know if you are using TeX Live (=MacTeX for the Mac) or MikTeX?

Comment: once I do that, how to cite? If I write /bibilography{MyBigBibFile} will it work on all .tex files?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes `\bibliography{MyBigBibFile}` is exactly right.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik So then follow the first direction. For an explanation of what the local `texmf` folder should look like, see [How to have local package override default package](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357)

Comment: There are 6 folders that has the name texmf :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Not in your home directory.  There should be one only in `~`  So you should have `~/texmf`. The others should be in `/usr/local/`. You should not touch them at all.

Comment: I will try to do this... Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this from Drop box folder? If I save it in ~, it will not be in the Drop box folder..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik you can make a symbolic link. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337952/2693 for an example.