# What is wrong with my use of biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Every time I compile my document and produce a PDF, it does not print my citations or references section. The preamble is copied below. I have a `.bib` file and all of the packages installed, the `.bib` file is in the same folder as the manuscript `.tex` file.

All the required packages are installed, and I have tried to fix this any number of ways, but with no luck. Does anyone have a suggestion? Note that I have tried to post a minimal working example in the code block. I am trying to get this to work on my own computer with the bibliography file I created from `Zotero`, rather than creating a new file contents on `LaTeX`, unless that is what you are supposed to do... I read the entire manual for `biblatex` but it does not explain clearly.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{kvoptions}
   \usepackage{url}
   \usepackage{csquotes}
   \usepackage{setspace}
   \usepackage{textcomp}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{amsthm}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \usepackage{logreq}
   \usepackage[sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
   \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
 %%\addbibresource{C:/Users/meese/Box/Research/SeekingButDefensive/NewSelfZoo/NewSelfZooBibliography.bib}

   \begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}

@article{karlsson_ostrich_2009,
    title = {The ostrich effect: Selective attention to information},
    volume = {38},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s11166-009-9060-6},
    pages = {95--115},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Risk and uncertainty},
    author = {Karlsson, Niklas and Loewenstein, George and Seppi, Duane},
    date = {2009},
    note = {Publisher: Springer},
}
   \end{filecontents}
   \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

   \begin{document}

   cite{karlsson_ostrich_2009}

   \printbibliography

   \end{document}
```

Comment: You're writing to a file called `\bibliography.bib`, instead of `bibliography.bib`. That could be a problem.

Comment: thanks @werner. I see what you are saying, but I just wrote that up for the sake of a minimally workable example to post, I put the code I am actually using after the line with %%. In my code, I don't have the file defined using the filecontents package, I am just trying to add the .bib resource to the biblatex package from a local file on my computer contained within the same folder as my .tex file...

Comment: Did you process your bibliography using `biber`?

Comment: Hi @werner, thank you so much for checking back in! I think I did, I included it in the options for biblatex -- [backend = biber]{biblatex}... is there another way to use biber appropriately? Thank you so much!

Comment: Biber is an external program/tool that has to run on your document (not unlike LaTeX) in order to produce a bibliography and citations. You need to compile your document with at least a cycle of LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...) for everything to resolve correctly. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains brilliantly what Biber does. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 helps you configure your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your actual question and very likely not the cause of your problems, but you do not need the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` and should remove it. That line was once needed in very old versions of `biblatex-apa`. It is no longer needed with newer versions of `biblatex-apa` and was never needed if you didn't load `style=apa,` (you don't).

Comment: Also unrelated to your problem, but the DOI given in the `doi` field should only contain the DOI, not the link portion `https://doi.org/` or `http://dx.doi.org/`. So `doi = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s11166-009-9060-6},` is wrong and should be `doi = {10.1007/s11166-009-9060-6},`. It is also extremely uncommon to give the publisher of a journal, so I would drop the `note = {Publisher: Springer},`.

Comment: Hi @moewe, thank you so much for your help! So, I should create a custom compilation in the typeset menu? I am using Miktex, should I be downloading another program to run biber, or is it installed through Miktex? Sorry if I sound super confused, the advice you have given so far is so helpful, and I am so grateful that you shared some of these extra details!

Comment: Also, @moewe, if you are still available, am I supposed to keep my bibliography file in a root directory somewhere?

Comment: What exactly you need to do depends on your editor (for most editors this is explained with pictures in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Biber is an external program that might have been installed automatically when you installed MikTeX. If it was not installed, you can install Biber via the MikTeX Console.

Comment: You don't have to keep your `.bib` file in a central location. It is fine to keep it in the same directory as your main `.tex` file. (There are ways to use one big central file and make it accessible from 'everywhere', but I would not worry about that at the moment. Put your `.bib` file in the same directory as your `.tex` file and see if you can get things going. Once things work, you can think about central `.bib` files: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6805/35864)

Comment: To check if Biber is installed correctly, open a terminal/console window (on Windows: hold Win+R, type in `cmd`, then hit enter) and type in `biber --version` and hit enter. After a while you should get a response like `biber version: 2.16`. If you have never used Biber before, this may take a while: Do *not* close the terminal window or do anything else to abort the Biber run in that case as that might lead to an incorrectly unpacked executable: Just wait. If Biber is not installed, you should get an error quickly.

Comment: @moewe, it just worked!!! Omg thank you so much!!! I appreciate your patience, the advice you gave was very helpful! I am trying to learn Latex, and spent maybe 6 hours trying to figure this out today... thank you for helping me resolve this!!!!